# xpath to get element a label is for (selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, label

I'm using the python package selenium to write a script that will automatically set up appointments for myself every week. What I ultimately want here is to be able to click the button with id="1103222339". I initially tried `driver.find_element_by_id("1103222339").click()`, but I cannot guarantee that every time I run this script that the appointment I need will correspond to this ID. To solve this issue, I want to look at the label that has text specifying the time and date of the appointment I want, then somehow retrieve the id through that for value.

[image]

I have not used XPath before, how do I find the element that a label is for through its text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build XPath expression locating the target `input` element based on the time, as following:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//label[contains(text(),'November 24, 2021 3:20 PM')]]//input").click()
```

Here you can, of cause, set the desired text according to your needs.
The XPath I built means: "locate `tr` element that has inside it a `label` element that contains `November 24, 2021 3:20 PM'` text. So inside this `tr` find an `input` element."
This is what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<input>` button element you can't use the `id="1103222339"` as it is dynamically generated and would change every time you access the application.

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.StrongText[for]").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@for and @class='StrongText'][contains(., 'November 24, 2021 3:20 PM')]").click()
  ```